# Acumatica - Creating Custom field with TEXT sql datatype

Tags: sql-server, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm trying to add a new custom field to the Customer page. The field is a "comment" field with formatted text in it. I know I'll have to use the PXRichTextEdit in my page and I need to add a SQL column of type `TEXT`, not `VARCHAR`.

My problem is that when I try to add a custom column in the table, the list of data types is this :

[image: List of data types in the Database Scripts tab]

By the way, I tried selecting "string" but this creates a column with the type `VARCHAR` and I get errors about truncating data when trying to save something in my column.

I successfully did it by creating manually the column in my SQL Server database (with SSMS), but I really don't want to do that when deploying in the production environment. I would prefer to have it in my personalisation package.

Is there a way to have it in the project ? Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: What is the limitation forcing use of TEXT? I don't think it's mapped in Acumatica and I would suggest nvarchar(max) for UNICODE.

Comment: The limitation I have comes from the PXRichTextEdit. It needs an SQL column with a maximum size limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation I have comes from the PXRichTextEdit. It needs an SQL column with a maximum size limit. The solution I found is to create a string column in the customization screen. Although the size is limited to 4000 characters, I created a database script to change the column size to `max`. With this, I don't have the error about truncating data and the SQL column is of type `varchar`.

Comment: you will want to use nvarchar(max). You can see the example on InventoryItem.Body which would be the same setup you are trying to implement. Maybe the issue is with adding a Usr field and no option for a max string to create the nvarchar(max)? As a custom table there is no problem using nvarchar(max) for a field related to a page using PXRichTextEdit